# Error while trying run the application in WebSphere

Tags: jsf, websphere

```
Exception Error Page

SRVE0260E: 
The server can not use the error page specified for your application to handle the original exception printed below.


Exception:

Message d''erreur: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/faces/application/Application.subscribeToEvent(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/faces/event/SystemEventListener;)V
Code d'erreur: 500
Servlet cible: 
Pile d'erreur: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/faces/application/Application.subscribeToEvent(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/faces/event/SystemEventListener;)V 
     at org.omnifaces.util.Events.subscribeToEvent(Events.java:171) 
     at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.InvokeActionEventListener.<init>(InvokeActionEventListener.java:65) 
     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1549) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:302) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:267) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureLifecycle(FacesConfigurator.java:888) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:279) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.update(FacesConfigurator.java:223) 
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:72) 
     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:149) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1667) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:944) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:374) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:828) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3954) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)
```

Comment: This is English-speaking website. In the future, you should translate the French into English. I already made an edit that may appear soon that will do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is a mismatch between the versions of MyFaces and the JSF API in your application and the server.  If you're intending to use your own JSF implementation packaged in your application, make sure you include both the implementation and API in the application or shared library, and make sure it's using a PARENT_LAST or isolated class loader.

If you're relying on WebSphere's implementation, double-check that you've selected the appropriate version in the application configuration (which actually changes the setting on the server) - in some versions of the server, you can change the implementation of JSF that you're using, which switches up which server libraries it picks up classes from.

Comment: hi jarid thanks your for your answer , i do all steps ,but still the same error

Comment: it work t forgot to chech ContextLoaderListener  in webspher